# addClass with delay to Elements using Waypoints and Each()

Tags: jquery, each, jquery-waypoints

I want to fade in multiple elements one by one with a delay between each, but I am using the same class as a selector.  I'm using `each()` to delay through each one and for some reason, some functions are working and some are not.

For example, fading out the elements one by one with JQuerys works:

```
$('.featured-properties').waypoint(function() {
    $('.props').each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(500*i).fadeOut(); 
    });
}, { offset: '70%' });
```

but adding a class does them all simultaneously:

```
$('.featured-properties').waypoint(function() {
    $('.props').each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(500*i).addClass('slide-in'); 
    });
}, { offset: '70%' });
```

My hope is to  have the animation created with CSS3, so I want to add a class, but for some reason it adds all of the classes at once.

THE HTML Markup -

```
<section class="container featured-properties">
    <div class="span25 props">
        <p>Some text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span25 props">
        <p>Some text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span25 props">
        <p>Some text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span25 props">
        <p>Some text...</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [DOC](https://api.jquery.com/delay/):

> Description: Set a timer to delay execution of subsequent items in the
>   queue.

You need to put relevant code in queue:

```
$(this).clearQueue().delay(500*i).queue(function(){$(this).addClass('slide-in');});
```

dequeue() or clearQueue() to keep the queue as clean as possible.

Or use a timeout instead.

Comment: Works.  Can you elaborate as to why in your answer?  Will mark accepted when it allows.  Very appreciated, thank you.

Comment: jQuery animation methods (animate, fadeIn, fadeOut, delay, etc) are put into a queue. addClass is not an animation method and is not queued, so you have to put it into the same queue as the animation method (delay) manually.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `setTimeout` instead of `delay` since `delay` only works with queues.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $(this).addClass('slide-in');
}, 500 * i);
```